# How does javascript work with while(true)-loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, browser, while-loop

Why does an infinite loop (even if you insert an alert and manually close it) cause the page to freeze? Its work fine for microcontrollers, but not for browsers. Why?

```
while(true) {
    alert();
}
```

In my understanding, there should be an endless call of a new alert when the old one is closed. This happens for a while, but then the browser freezes.

Yes, I know about the existence of requestAnimationFrame and setInterval, but I want to understand what is the problem with infinite loops.

Comment: Why wouldn't it freeze? The thread is occupied running a loop.

Comment: Javascript in the browser works on a single thread. Note that the browser creates a seperate 'thread' (without going into too much detail) for functions like `setTimeout` or async functions. This means that the page will execute the while loop until it is complete, so it freezes.

Comment: why it stuck after some time? Where is the timer for "it's time to freeze this thread"?

Comment: Microcontrollers and browsers are very different things. For this reason, according to me, it's no surprise that something fine for one it's not for the other.

Comment: It's not only that JS runs in a single thread, the freeze happens, because HTML rendering, event listening and many other browser jobs use the same thread, and when you reserve the thread with an infinite loop, browser can't do any other jobs and "freezes".

Comment: "_why it stuck after some time?_" It is stuck as soon as it enters the loop. Though it might take the browser some time to realize that it is actually stuck. (Especially since `alert()` is a synchronous operation that also pauses the thread, but waiting for an alert doesn't mean that it is stuck.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, I found answer with yours help!
Here its descripbed well:

**Concurrency model and the event loop**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Quote from **"Run-to-completion"** part:

"...A downside of this model is that if a message takes too long to complete, the web application is unable to process user interactions like click or scroll. The browser mitigates this with the "a script is taking too long to run" dialog. A good practice to follow is to make message processing short and if possible cut down one message into several messages."